# Drupal database does not show table name

Tags: mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin

I have installed drupal in my localhost ( not in xampp or wamp custom php, mysql, apache installation on my windows machine ).  However when I visit my database using phpmyadmin it shows table description instead of table name, when I list all tables ( even in left side frame ).

Is there any way so that I can see table name instead of description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution myself.

This has nothing to do with drupal installation, it is just phpmyadmin settings.

Navigate to the the landing page of phpmyadmin.

From there Settings > Navigation Frame > Tables > and set "Display table comment instead of its name" to "no/nested"

It worked for me.